# FabricJs: Limit grouping to only 1 level deep - Ungroup all objects before grouping

Tags: fabricjs

I do not want the user to be able to group a grouped item within another group. My solution to achieve this is basically when the user clicks on the 'Group' button, I am ungrouping everything and then grouping the selection again.

My problem is that when this happens, the items that are ungrouped, become duplicates. One set on the canvas, and one set within the new group.

Here is a video of what I mean...
https://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/cbXQfa2lJg

Here is my code...

```
export function groupSelectedItems() {

  canvas = document.getElementById("c").fabric;
  var activegroup = canvas.getActiveGroup();
  var objectsInGroup = activegroup.getObjects();

  //Ungroup all items first. This will limit grouping to only one level deep.
  objectsInGroup.forEach(function(o) {

      if(o.type=="group"){

        //ungroup items within this group
        var items = o.getObjects();

        o.destroy();
        canvas.remove(o);

        items.forEach(function(i) {
          canvas.add(i);
          activegroup.addWithUpdate(i)
          canvas.renderAll();
        });
      }
  });

  //Create the group
  activegroup.clone(function(newgroup) {

    canvas.discardActiveGroup();
    objectsInGroup.forEach(function(object) {
        canvas.remove(object);
    });

    canvas.add(newgroup);
    newgroup.setControlsVisibility({'tl': false, 'tr': false, 'bl': false, 'br': false, 'ml': false, 'mr': false, 'mb': false, 'mt': false});

  }, ['id', 'componentType', 'shape']);

  canvas.renderAll();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function groupSelectedItems() {
  canvas = document.getElementById("c").fabric;
  var activegroup = canvas.getActiveGroup();

  activegroup.clone(function(newgroup) {
    canvas.discardActiveGroup();
    activegroup.forEachObject(function(object) {
      canvas.remove(object);
    });
    newgroup.forEachObject(function(object) {
      if (object.type == 'group') {
        object.destroy();
        newgroup.removeWithUpdate(object);
        object.forEachObject(function(obj) {
          newgroup.addWithUpdate(obj);
        })
      }
    });
    canvas.add(newgroup);
  }, ['id', 'componentType', 'shape']);
}
```

Check all the object in group, if any group object is present then ungroup all the object and then add to canvas.